# Gitlab markdown links to artifacts

Tags: gitlab

Is it possible in Gitlab to have source controlled markdown that contains a link to an artifact?

My runner generates metrics that are saved to a file. This output, of course, does not belong in version control. If it *was* in version control, I could just link to it, no problem.  Instead, I mark the output as an artifact so that it is saved after the build is complete.

Currently, our devs can click the [passed] icon for the build that generates the metrics, then click 'Build Artifacts'|'Browse'|dir1|... down to the generated output metric. This is complicated, and you have to know exactly where to look.

It would be way more convenient to have a link to the artifact in the README.md.

These [docs](http://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/build_artifacts/README.html#defining-artifacts-in-gitlab-ciyml) say that I can choose to store my artifacts in a different location, but that seems like a heavy solution, and it does not generalize to artifacts from different projects.

These [docs](http://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/yaml/README.html#artifacts) say that I can embed build numbers in the artifact filename, but that's not really what I'm after.  I just want the artifacts from the most recent build.

What I want is a persistent URL for the artifact, but I am unable to find anything of this nature.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update February 2018**:

Since Gitlab 8.12, the link is *https://**gitlabInstance**/**myNamespace**/repository/master/archive.zip*. (e.g: https://gitlab.com/rpadovani/my-gitlab-ci/repository/master/archive.zip).

There are also other formats.

You can see all the formats clicking on the little cloud in the top right of the homepage of your project.
[image: download link]

**ORIGINAL ANSWER**

They are working on it right now.

Since GitLab 8.10, there is an API to do that:

```
curl -H "PRIVATE-TOKEN: 9koXpg98eAheJpvBs5tK" "https://gitlab.example.com/api/v3/projects/1/builds/artifacts/master/download?job=test"
```

Unfortunately you still cannot use the web interface, but there is already a [MR](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/merge_requests/5142) to implement it (and a [related bug](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/4255) with discussion).

After that MR you can link the build in your README